# Firestore - Add documents to an existing array - Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I read data from Firestore using Firebase. Using Firebase's pagination function, I then try to add the new values to an array. But Typescript throws me a message when I try to call the setState hook.

```
interface DOCUMENT {
 docId: string;
 title: string;
 coverImage: string;
 width: number;
 height: number;
 likesId: string[];
 follower: string[];
 hasChecked: boolean;
}

export default function Home() {

const [results, setResults] = useState<DOCUMENT[]>([]);


useEffect(() => {
const nextOnes = async () => {
  const documents: DOCUMENT[] = [];

  const next = query(
    collection(db, "documents"),
    orderBy("createdAt", "asc"),
    startAfter(lastVisible),
    limit(3)
  );
  const documentSnapshots = await getDocs(next);

  documentSnapshots.forEach((doc) => {
    documents.push(doc.data() as DOCUMENT);
  });

  //Error throw here
  setResults((prev) => [...prev, documents]);
};

inView && nextOnes();
}, [inView, lastVisible]);


...

}
```

> Argument of type '(prev: DOCUMENT[]) => (DOCUMENT | DOCUMENT[])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<DOCUMENT[]>'.
> Type '(prev: DOCUMENT[]) => (DOCUMENT | DOCUMENT[])[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: DOCUMENT[]) => DOCUMENT[]'.
> Type '(DOCUMENT | DOCUMENT[])[]' is not assignable to type 'DOCUMENT[]'.
> Type 'DOCUMENT | DOCUMENT[]' is not assignable to type 'DOCUMENT'.
> Type 'DOCUMENT[]' is missing the following properties from type 'DOCUMENT': docId, title, coverImage, width, and 4 more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to spread your `documents` array for inclusion into the final array of results, just like you are already doing with `prev`.

```
  setResults((prev) => [...prev, ...documents]);
```